# How to show data in columns rather than rows based on condition in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a table tt_players which have 3 columns.

### Table structure

[image]

And the result I want is in this way.

[image]

Note that, the record with same reservation_id should come in column. I know that the rows with same reservation_id will not increase from 3.

I tried Group BY clause but could not achieve what I want. Any help or hint will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be something of a headache to write a query which matches your literal expected output.  But using `GROUP_CONCAT` we can arrive at something which is very close:

```
SELECT
    reservation_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(player_id ORDER BY player_id) players
FROM
    yourTable
GROUP BY
    reservation_id;
```

[image]

One reason this is possibly preferable to what you expect is that if a given reservation should ever have more than 3 players at some point in the future, my query would simply add a new player to the CSV list of players.  If we go for the exact output without dynamic SQL, the presence of a fourth player could break the query.

### Demo

Comment: Seems like this is the best way doing it. Actually I am writing query report in jasper. so I dont know if it can detect the CSV and separate it in different columns or not.

Comment: The same problem exists in your reporting layer, namely what happens when a fourth player turns up.  If you really need your exact output I can try it or someone else can, let us know.

Comment: This is the requirement of the report. In that case, we need to create another report. this report will not work anymore

Comment: @SyedHassan I started on a query, and it was so ugly that I got scared and gave up.  Maybe someone else can help you here, personally I would just deal with the CSV on the Jasper reporting side.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts Tim! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use Pivoting

```
SELECT   [reservation_id], player_id
FROM   [dbo].[PivotExample] 
PIVOT
(

       FOR [player_id] IN ([1], [2], [4], [5])
) AS P
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support `PIVOT` as far as I know.

Comment: Even if it works in MySQL, I can not use it because I don't know how many player_ids do I have